# Проблема с GLUT, GLAUX, SDL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Это случилось после удаления GLaux.lib с проекта и папки VC\include.

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: evoluRia, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _SDL_GetError в функции "unsigned int __cdecl EV_LOAD_TEX(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?EV_LOAD_TEX@@YAIV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _SDL_FreeSurface в функции "unsigned int __cdecl EV_LOAD_TEX(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?EV_LOAD_TEX@@YAIV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _IMG_Load в функции "unsigned int __cdecl EV_LOAD_TEX(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?EV_LOAD_TEX@@YAIV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _main в функции ___tmainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\Вамиг\Desktop\Программирование\Проекты\evoluRia\evoluRia\Debug\evoluRia.exe : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 4
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

main.cpp

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include <gl\glut.h>

#define EV_NAME "evoluRia"
#define EV_VER  "0.1"
#define EV_C_EXIT 100
#define EV_C_ABOUT 101

char EV_NAME_V[20] = "evoluRia v.";
bool EV_GAME = true;
int EV_MAX_FPS = 0, EV_FPS = 0,
    EV_FUS_FR, EV_FPS_OLD = 1;

#include "__graphicsFunc.h"
#include "__playerClass.h"

unsigned int textures[6];
float EV_SKYSIZE[3],
    EV_NULL_P[3];

//Рисование...
void EV_DISPLAY() {
    //////////////////////////////////////
    //= Mouse Check ====================//
    __pl.mouse();                       //
    //= Keyboard Check =================//
    if (EV_FORWARD_PR)                  //
        __pl.keyboard2(EV_FORWARD_KEY); //
    else if (EV_BACK_PR)                //
        __pl.keyboard2(EV_BACK_KEY);    //
                                        //
    if (EV_LEFT_PR)                     //
        __pl.keyboard2(EV_LEFT_KEY);    //
    else if (EV_RIGHT_PR)               //
        __pl.keyboard2(EV_RIGHT_KEY);   //
                                        //
    if (EV_UP_PR)                       //
        __pl.keyboard2(EV_UP_KEY);      //
    else if (EV_DOWN_PR)                //
        __pl.keyboard2(EV_DOWN_KEY);    //
    //////////////////////////////////////

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    __pl.apply();
    glTranslatef(__pl.x, __pl.y, __pl.z);
    EV_CREATE_PARALLELEPIPEDf(EV_NULL_P, EV_SKYSIZE, textures);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();

    ++EV_FPS;
}

void EV_INIT() {
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 1.33, 0.01, 3696);

    //Задаем матрицу по умолчанию.
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    EV_NULL_P[0] = 0;
    EV_NULL_P[1] = 0;
    EV_NULL_P[2] = 0;

    //- Skybox ---------------------------------//
    textures[0] = EV_LOAD_TEX("2\\top.bmp");    //
    textures[1] = EV_LOAD_TEX("2\\bottom.bmp"); //
    textures[2] = EV_LOAD_TEX("2\\front.bmp");  //
    textures[3] = EV_LOAD_TEX("2\\back.bmp");   //
    textures[4] = EV_LOAD_TEX("2\\left.bmp");   //
    textures[5] = EV_LOAD_TEX("2\\right.bmp");  //
                                                //
    EV_SKYSIZE[0] = 4096;                       //
    EV_SKYSIZE[1] = 4096;                       //
    EV_SKYSIZE[2] = 4096;                       //
    //------------------------------------------//
}

void EV_KEY(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key)
    {
    case 'w': EV_FORWARD_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'a': EV_LEFT_PR = true;
        break;
    case 's': EV_BACK_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'd': EV_RIGHT_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'c': EV_DOWN_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'W': EV_FORWARD_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'A': EV_LEFT_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'S': EV_BACK_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'D': EV_RIGHT_PR = true;
        break;
    case 'C': EV_DOWN_PR = true;
        break;
    case ' ': EV_UP_PR = true;
    }
}

void EV_KEY_UP(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key)
    {
    case 'w': EV_FORWARD_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'a': EV_LEFT_PR = false;
        break;
    case 's': EV_BACK_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'd': EV_RIGHT_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'c': EV_DOWN_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'W': EV_FORWARD_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'A': EV_LEFT_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'S': EV_BACK_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'D': EV_RIGHT_PR = false;
        break;
    case 'C': EV_DOWN_PR = false;
        break;
    case ' ': EV_UP_PR = false;
    }
}

void EV_KEY_S(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP: EV_FORWARD_PR = true;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: EV_LEFT_PR = true;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: EV_BACK_PR = true;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: EV_RIGHT_PR = true;
        break;
    }
}

void EV_KEY_S_UP(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP: EV_FORWARD_PR = false;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: EV_LEFT_PR = false;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: EV_BACK_PR = false;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: EV_RIGHT_PR = false;
        break;
    }
}

void EV_MENU_WORK(int v) {
    switch (v)
    {
    case EV_C_EXIT: glutDestroyWindow(glutGetWindow()); EV_GAME = false;
        break;
    case EV_C_ABOUT:
        break;
    }
}

void EV_MENU_INIT() {
    int m = glutCreateMenu(EV_MENU_WORK);

    glutSetMenu(m);
    glutAddMenuEntry("About", EV_C_ABOUT);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Exit",  EV_C_EXIT);

    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_MIDDLE_BUTTON);
}

void EV_FRAME_TIMER(int) {
    if (!EV_GAME)
        return;

    char EV_FPS_R[4];
    EV_FPS_OLD = EV_FPS;
    sprintf(EV_FPS_R, "%d", EV_FPS);

    glutSetWindowTitle(EV_FPS_R);
    __pl.fps_reload();
    EV_FPS = 0;

    glutTimerFunc(1000, EV_FRAME_TIMER, 0);
}

void EV_REDISPLAY(int) {
    if (!EV_GAME)
        return;

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(EV_FUS_FR, EV_REDISPLAY, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Инициализация...
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow(strcat(EV_NAME_V, EV_VER));

    if (EV_MAX_FPS == 0)
        EV_FUS_FR = 0;
    else
        EV_FUS_FR = 1000 / EV_MAX_FPS;

    //Регистрация функций...
    glutDisplayFunc(EV_DISPLAY);
    glutTimerFunc(1000, EV_FRAME_TIMER, 0);
    glutTimerFunc(EV_FUS_FR, EV_REDISPLAY, 0);
    glutKeyboardFunc(EV_KEY);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(EV_KEY_UP);
    glutSpecialFunc(EV_KEY_S);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(EV_KEY_S_UP);
    EV_INIT();
    EV_MENU_INIT();

    //Вход в основной цикл...
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

__graphicsFunc.h

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>

#define GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE 0x812F

GLuint EV_LOAD_TEX(std::string fileName) {
    int EV_COLOR_T;
    unsigned int texture = 0;
    SDL_Surface* img = IMG_Load(fileName.c_str());

    if (!img)
        std::cerr << "Unable to download texture. Code: " << IMG_GetError() << std::endl;

    if (img->format->BitsPerPixel == 24)
        EV_COLOR_T = GL_RGB;
    else
        EV_COLOR_T = GL_RGBA;

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, EV_COLOR_T, img->w, img->h, EV_COLOR_T, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img->pixels);

    SDL_FreeSurface(img);
    return texture;
}

void EV_CREATE_PARALLELEPIPEDf(float pos[3], float size[3], unsigned int texture[6]) {
    float size_d[3];
    size_d[0] = size[0] / 2;
    size_d[1] = size[1] / 2;
    size_d[2] = size[2] / 2;

    //Front
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);  glVertex3f(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3f(-size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);    glVertex3f(size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);   glVertex3f(size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Back
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);  glVertex3f(size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3f(size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);  glVertex3f(-size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Left
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[4]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);  glVertex3f(-size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f(-size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);  glVertex3f(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Right
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[5]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3f(size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);    glVertex3f(size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f(size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);  glVertex3f(size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Bottom
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);  glVertex3f(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f(size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);  glVertex3f(size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Top
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3f(-size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);  glVertex3f(-size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3f(size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);    glVertex3f(size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glEnd();
}

void EV_CREATE_PARALLELEPIPEDd(double pos[], double size[], unsigned int texture[]) {
    double size_d[3];
    size_d[0] = size[0] / 2;
    size_d[1] = size[1] / 2;
    size_d[2] = size[2] / 2;

    //Front
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[2]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);  glVertex3d(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3d(-size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);    glVertex3d(size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);   glVertex3d(size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Back
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[3]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);  glVertex3d(size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);   glVertex3d(size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);  glVertex3d(-size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3d(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Left
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[4]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3d(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);  glVertex3d(-size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3d(-size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);  glVertex3d(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Right
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[5]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3d(size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);    glVertex3d(size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3d(size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);  glVertex3d(size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Bottom
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3d(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);  glVertex3d(-size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3d(size_d[0], -size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);  glVertex3d(size_d[0], -size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glEnd();

    //Top
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);   glVertex3d(-size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);  glVertex3d(-size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);   glVertex3d(size_d[0], size_d[1], -size_d[2]);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);    glVertex3d(size_d[0], size_d[1], size_d[2]);
    glEnd();
}
```

__playerClass.h

```
#include <cmath>
#define PI 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286208998628034825342117067982148086513282306647093845

#define EV_FORWARD_KEY 200
#define EV_LEFT_KEY    201
#define EV_BACK_KEY    202
#define EV_RIGHT_KEY   203
#define EV_UP_KEY      204
#define EV_DOWN_KEY    205

bool EV_FORWARD_PR = false, EV_LEFT_PR = false, EV_BACK_PR = false, EV_RIGHT_PR = false,
    EV_UP_PR = false, EV_DOWN_PR = false;

class EV_PLAYER {
public:
    float angleX = 0, angleY = 0;
    double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, speed = 90, speed_op = 1,
        w = 1, h = 1, d = 1, h_eye = 1;

    EV_PLAYER() {
        ShowCursor(false);
    }

    void mouse() {
        POINT EV_M_POS;
        GetCursorPos(&EV_M_POS);

        angleX += (600 - EV_M_POS.x) / 4;
        angleY += (500 - EV_M_POS.y) / 4;

        if (angleX > 359.99)
            angleX -= 360;
        else if (angleX < -359.99)
            angleX += 360;

        if (angleY < -89.99)
            angleY = -89.99;
        else if (angleY > 89.99)
            angleY = 89.99;

        SetCursorPos(600, 500);
    }

    void keyboard1(int key) {
        if (key == EV_FORWARD_KEY) {
            x += -sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            y +=  tan(angleY / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z += -cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }else if (key == EV_BACK_KEY) {
            x +=  sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            y += -tan(angleY / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z +=  cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }

        if (key == EV_LEFT_KEY) {
            x += sin((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z += cos((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }else if (key == EV_RIGHT_KEY) {
            x += sin((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z += cos((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }

        if (key == EV_UP_KEY)
            y += speed_op;
        else if (key == EV_DOWN_KEY)
            y -= speed_op;
    }

    void keyboard2(int key, bool free = true) {
        if (key == EV_FORWARD_KEY) {
            x -= sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z -= cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }else if (key == EV_BACK_KEY) {
            x += sin(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z += cos(angleX / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }

        if (key == EV_LEFT_KEY) {
            x += sin((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z += cos((angleX - 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }else if (key == EV_RIGHT_KEY) {
            x += sin((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
            z += cos((angleX + 90) / 180 * PI) * speed_op;
        }

        if (key == EV_UP_KEY) {
            if (free)
                y += speed_op;
            else
                jump();
        }else if (key == EV_DOWN_KEY)
            if(free)
                y -= speed_op;
    }

    void jump() {

    }

    void fps_reload() {
        speed_op = speed / EV_FPS_OLD;
    }

    void apply() {
        gluLookAt(x, y + h_eye, z, x - sin(angleX / 180 * PI), y + h_eye + (tan(angleY / 180 * PI)), z - cos(angleX / 180 * PI), 0, 1, 0);
    }
}__pl;
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта ошибка линкера

> error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ

означает что метод объявлен (в одном из заголовков), но при линковке не найден ни в одном из ваших модулей, ни в подключенных lib.

Скачайте [SDL Development Libraries для Visual C++ 32/64-bit](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php), распакуйте.

Скопируйте в проект `SDL2.lib` и `SDL2main.lib` из папки `lib` нужной битности.

После этого добавьте обе `.lib` в список `Project`/`Properties`/`Configuration Properties`/`Linker`/`Input`/`Additional Dependencies`.

Это есть в [официальном гайде](http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/VisualC.html), но он написан для VC7, могу немного устареть.

Comment: Нет, оказалось, что проблема в SDL, но как установить правильно SDL?

Comment: @Vamig ок, сейчас допишу

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Галку я отметил, но увеличить репутацию не получается.